# How to create ggsurvfit facet plot

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

Within the '''library(ggsurvfit)''' package, how do you create a facet plot using the `ggsurvfit()` function?

I was under the impression that `library(ggsurvfit)` integrated with `ggplot2` and so facet should be as normal. Hence I tried the below but with no luck.

```
library(survival)
library(ggsurvfit)

dat <- structure(list(Rabbit = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 26L, 34L, 35L, 28L, 29L, 32L, 36L, 30L, 31L, 
33L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L), Treatment = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("Meat bait", 
"Soil spray", "Carrot bait", "Oat bait", "Control"), class = "factor"), 
    Survival.Time.Rabbit = c(68.5, 75, 51, 51, 99, 120, 240, 
    219, 336, 53, 29, 77, 77, 96, 149, 91.5, 77, 336, 336, 336, 
    77.67, 92.67, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 53.5, 73, 
    336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336), Status.Rabbit = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Timepoint = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), levels = c("1 Day post exposure", 
    "5 Days post exposure", "10 Days post exposure", "20 Days post exposure", 
    "40 Days post exposure", "60 Days post exposure"), class = "factor"), 
    Survival.Time.Bait1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 10L, 10L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20L, 20L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Survival.Time.Bait2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 
    10L, 10L, NA, NA, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, NA, 
    NA, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 60L, 60L, 60L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = "data.frame")

survfit2(Surv(Survival.Time.Rabbit, Status.Rabbit) ~ Timepoint, data = dat) %>% 
  ggsurvfit(linewidth = 1.5) + 
  labs(x = "Time to death (hours)", 
       y = "Survival probability") + 
  add_confidence_interval() + 
  add_pvalue("annotation", caption = "Log-rank {p.value}", size = 4) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Treatment, nrow = 2)
```

From the above code I was expecting separate survival plots for each treatment that showed Kaplan-Meier curves for each time point. Instead I get the below error message.

```
Error in `combine_vars()`:
! At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `Treatment`
✖ Plot is missing `Treatment`
✖ Layer 1 is missing `Treatment`
✖ Layer 2 is missing `Treatment`
✖ Layer 3 is missing `Treatment`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I have tried to debug this message by following solutions to several similar problems to no avail ([Solution1](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-at-least-one-layer-must-contain-all-faceting-variables-for-dumbbell-plot/121399), [Solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71859648/error-in-combine-vars-at-least-one-layer-must-contain-all-faceting-variab), [Solution3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591051/at-least-one-layer-must-contain-all-variables-used-for-facetting))

Comment: Can you share some sample data using `dput()` ? It makes it easier to help if we can run your code. More general info on facetting ggsurvfit here: http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/ggsurvfit/articles/gallery.html#faceting

Comment: Thanks. I now include the data through ```dput()```, as suggested, the error message that I receive and the solutions that I have tried.